# Basic set operations: Simplify (A−Bc)∪(B∩(A∩B)c).

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Could someone please help with answering the questions below?

Question 1: Simplify $(A−B^c)∪(B∩(A∩B)^c).$

Question 2: Simplify $(A∪B)∪(C∩A)∪(A∩B)^c.$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for $2$nd question**. (I suggest you to **draw this sets**, it would be much easier.)

Since $C\cap A\subseteq A \subset A\cup B$ we have $$(A∪B)∪(C∩A)= A\cup B$$

Since $A\subset A\cup B$ and $A'\subseteq A'\cup B' = (A\cap B)'$
we have $$U = A\cup A' \subseteq (A\cup B)\cup (A\cap B)'$$ so the result is whole universal set $U$.

---

**$1$st question.**

Since $A−B^c = A\cap B$ and $B∩(A∩B)^c = B- A$ we get

$$(A−B^c)∪(B∩(A∩B)^c) = (A\cap B)\cup (B-A) = B$$

Comment: Is this answer of no use to you?

Answer (score -1):

I will show you how to solve question one and proceed similarly to question 2 , note that A-Bˣ=A∩B then it equals to (A∩B)∪(B∩(A∩B)ˣ)=B∩(A∪(A∩B)ˣ) then using demorgan rules it equals to B∩(A∪(Aˣ∪Bˣ))=B cus B⊂A∪Aˣ

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Why would A-B' = A∩B? as B' is the complement of B which does not include A∩B I think, could you please draw a venn diagram for clearer explanation?

Comment: x∈A∩B ⇔ x in A and x not in Bˣ cus x im B ⇔ x in A-Bˣ